# How to not count rows twice if they have same value in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a visitor tracking system. I track visitor ips and browser. I can count total visits (total rows), but how can I count unique visits ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Distinct`:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT visits) from Table;
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `GROUP BY` on IP, or IP+browser!
`SELECT COUNT(ip) FROM yourtable GROUP BY ip`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will give you "unique visitors" as measured by distinct browser/IP hits:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS unique_visitors FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ip, browser FROM visitors
) a
```